# Macbook Pro 2020 Fingerprint sensor not working in Windows 10 Pro x64 Bootcamp

Tags: windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp, fingerprint

The fingerprint sensor (which doubles in as the power button) on the new Macbook Pro dones't get detected in Windows 10 Pro x64 Bootcamp partition. I checked the Device Manager and the Fingerprint sensor does not get detected there even upon refresh. Is there a way I could make it work with Windows as well?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it can be done. There was a lot of discussion on this when TouchID first came to the Mac. My guess is Windows will not be allowed anywhere near the Secure Enclave.